# Text box with drop down suggestions

Tags: autocomplete, drop-down-menu, asp.net-2.0

I currently have a databound dropdown list on my ASP.Net C# 2.0 website that has around 400 items in it. I want to replace it with something similar like the textbox in google search where you enter letter and only the entries starting with those letters pop up

what is a good way of implementing it? Are there controls that already exists that anybody can suggest?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete

Also here is a [tutorial](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/18b6a1fa-a7cf-4507-84f2-15056fe65bb7/autocompletion-with-jque.aspx) for use with ASP.Net

Answer (score 13):

One way to do this using HTML5 (for small datasets of course) is `datalist`:

```
<input list="users" name="users">
  <datalist id="users">
    <option value="Alice">
    <option value="Bob">
    <option value="Chuck">
    <option value="Chris">
    <option value="Duke">
    <option value="Emily">
  </datalist>
```

For larger datasets AJAX is a better way to go.

Answer (score 4):

check complete.ly too

http://complete-ly.appspot.com/

it has no dependencies and weights very little.

Answer (score 1):

If these are known enrties, you can use JQuery, and on the OnUpdate event:

1. if it's a long list, make Ajax Request to your webserver, retrieve the best option
2. if it's a short list, you can load all the options to the page, and offer the optional texts without making a server request.

Checkout the JQuery library for implementations on how to display the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

There's an [AutoComplete](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx) extender as past of the AJAX Control Toolkit for ASP.NET. There are plenty of different options that you can set for client caching, delay interval. Just point it at a web service or page method and away you go.

Answer (score 0):

TextBoxValueToDropDownList

```
    function AddNames(text) {

        if (document.myForm.insertText.value == "") {
            document.getElementById("insertText").style.border = "1px solid red";
            return false;
        }
        else {
            var option = document.createElement("OPTION");
            option.text = text.value;
            option.value = text.value;
            document.getElementById("dropDownList").options.add(option);
            document.myForm.insertText.value = "";
            document.getElementById("insertText").style.border = "1px solid green";
        }
    }




    <form name="myForm">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="insertText" id="insertText" /></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <select name="dropDown" id="dropDownList">
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" value="Insert" id="button" onclick="AddNames(insertText);" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```